# Migrating ServletRequestListener after adopting spring-sessions

Tags: spring-session, servlet-listeners

We recently started integrating spring-session in our project. This is a SOA based application and have some logic implementations to manage sessions.

1. HttpSessionListener which we use to log out the sessions in case of timeout and monitored through sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent).
2. ServletRequestListener which we use to manage HTTP session invalidations. This is implemented in requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent servletRequestEvent) method.

For item #1, I found an article [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/httpsession.html#httpsession-jdbc-xml), which describes the use of SessionEventHttpSessionListenerAdapter as supported by Spring Session. And have this configuration added in my session.xml.

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionEventHttpSessionListenerAdapter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.MyHttpSessionListener"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Also added below configuration in my deployment descriptor (e.g. web.xml)

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

After some debugging, I have noticed that my HttpSessionListener is using the session provided by spring session.

However, for item #2, using ServletRequestListener implementation, I could not find a way to migrate it to spring session. It is still using the session provided by the container.

Is there a corresponding adapter, like SessionEventHttpSessionListenerAdapter, intended for ServletRequestListener? Is this supported by Spring Session? What other options do I have to get our functionality working with spring session?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using custom Filter to manage HTTP session invalidation. Modified the web.xml with the following entries in sequence:

(a) Register springSessionRepositoryFilter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

(b) Add requestContextFilter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

(c) Add custom filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>myCustomServletRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.xxx.xxx.xxx.servlet.filter.MyCustomServletRequestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myCustomServletRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

(d) Load spring session context

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

All HTTP requests are now using spring session.

Comment: Encountered another problem on succeeding requests. It gets redirected to the login page. Checking at some resources, it might be related to CORS setup as I am seeing these new request header values: **Sec-Fetch-Site**, **Sec-Fetch-Mode**, **Sec-Fetch-Dest**, **sec-ch-ua**, **sec-ch-ua-mobile**. These headers were not returned/included before the spring session integration. If someone encountered the same issue, please advise how did you fix it.